# Tile Loaded Event in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I wanted to know tile loaded event in ArcGIS API for JavaScript. As soon as tile is loaded this event should be called which give me tile specific information like tiles coordinates etc.

Comment: There is no ready made event for this. You'll probably have to make and use a custom layer which gives out these kinds of events.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aspect oriented programming to intercept the start of end of a function

More info here on dojo aspect. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html

```
aspect.before(tiledLayer, "_addImage", function() {

  // you will have all the info you need in the arguments array

}, true)
```